# Python: merge first list with each list within list

Tags: python, list

I have the list:

```
list_mix = [['1','2','3'],['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
```

The first list must be merged with other lists in the list_mis. The result should be:

```
['1','2','3','a','b','c']
['1','2','3','d','e','f']
['1','2','3','g','h','i']
```

The following code gives me "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list":

```
for item in list_mix[1:]:
    print (list_mix[0] + list_mix[item])
```

Any solution without external libraries would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item` is the sublist *already*, *not* an index. Just use it directly:

```
for item in list_mix[1:]:
    print (list_mix[0] + item)
```

The Python `for` statement is a [Foreach loop construct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop), assigning each element from `list_mix[1:]` to `item` in turn.

Demo:

```
>>> list_mix = [['1','2','3'],['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i']]
>>> for item in list_mix[1:]:
...     print (list_mix[0] + item)
... 
['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c']
['1', '2', '3', 'd', 'e', 'f']
['1', '2', '3', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension add every sublist to sublist 0 of `list_mix`, `use list_mix[1:]` to start at the element after `['1','2','3']`.

```
[list_mix[0] + x for x in list_mix[1:]]
[['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['1', '2', '3', 'g', 'h', 'i']]
```